# explicitly splitting the hamilton quaternions over local fields

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

For simplicity, lets first consider the hamilton quaternions $$ H = \left(\frac{-1,-1}{\mathbb{Q}}\right)$$
This is the central division algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$ with $\mathbb{Q}$-basis given by $1,i,j,ij$ subject to the relations $i^2 = j^2 = -1, ij = -ji$.

Over any field $K$ containing $\sqrt{-1}$, one finds that the matrices
$$1 = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix},\qquad i = \begin{bmatrix} i & 0 \\ 0 & -i\end{bmatrix},\qquad j = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix},\qquad ij = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & i \\ i & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
Satisfies the given relations and so explicitly describes the splitting for any such field $K$.

It's known that $H$ is ramified only at 2 and $\infty$, so $H\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{Q}_p\cong M_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ for all odd primes $p$. If $p\equiv 1\mod 4$, then $i\in\mathbb{Q}_p$, and so the above gives an explicit splitting in such cases.

My question is, what happens if $p\equiv 3\mod 4$? Is there an easy way to describe the splitting explicitly as above in this case?